How to run serenity suites in net beans
Is any one ran serenity BDD suites in net beans/visual studio / visual code, I would like to know how to set up and run serenity in net beans. any help is appreciated.
I tried many ways mentioned online and nothing has worked out.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
